# What is the common pattern to use MemoryCache instead of ConccurentDictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, memorycache

My code handle concurrent request by waiting the result of an already running operation. Requests for data may come in simultaneously with same/different credentials(including empty credential).

For each unique set of credentials there can be at most one GetDataInternal call in progress, with the result from that one call returned to all queued waiters when it is ready

```
private static readonly Credentials EmptyCredentials = 
new Credentials
{
    SqlCredentials = null,
    ExchangeCredentials = null
}; // added it to avoid ArgumentNullException inside GetOrAdd if Credentials == null

private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Credentials, Lazy<Data>> Cache = 
             new ConcurrentDictionary<Credentials, Lazy<Data>>();

public Data GetData(Credentials credential)
{
    Lazy<Data> data = new Lazy<Data>(() => GetDataInternal(credential));
    Lazy<Data> lazyData = Cache.GetOrAdd(credential ?? EmptyCredentials, data);

    bool isAdded = ReferenceEquals(data, lazyData); 

    try
    {
       return lazyData.Value;
    }
    finally
    {
       if (isAdded)
       {
            Cache.TryRemove(credential ?? EmptyCredentials, out lazyData);
        }
    }
}
```

I added `finally` block, because I need to update my dictionary (maintain up to date). Only the thread which created the cache value is allowed to remove it, to prevent races.

But I want to stop using `ConccurentDictionary` and `finally` block and instead of that I would like to use `MemoryCache`. The `MemoryCache` has an eviction strategy, so that it can throw out entries that are no longer needed or for that you do not have enough memory anymore. Its exactly what I need.

How can I change the following line

```
Lazy<Data> lazyData = Cache.GetOrAdd(credential ?? EmptyCredentials, data);
```

by using MemoryCache?

```
Lazy<Data> lazyData = (Lazy<Data>)MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(..., data, 
                                                                    new CacheItemPolicy());
```

So, how can I get my key value?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following solution, but I'm not sure is it correct

```
public Data GetData(Credentials credential)
{
   var data = new Lazy<Data>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credential));
   var lazydata  = (Lazy<Data>)MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(
                   (credential ?? EmptyMetadataCredentials).ToString(),
                    data,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));

    return (lazydata ?? data).Value;
}
```